# how to create new credentials in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In short, there is a credential configured manaully to connect to `host01` as `root`.

The jenkins pipeline is to create a new ssh-login, such as `dev01`, in `host01`. After creating the `dev01` by using `root`, the rest of the pipeline is to do some tasks as `dev01` instead of `root`. This procedure may repeat several times to create different ssh-logins, such as `dev02`, `dev03`, and etc.

The question is how to create a new credenials (username and secrect-key) in jenkins pipeline script for connectting to `host01` as `dev01`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, some code can help. There are different types of credentials in Jenkins, one of them is "secret text" that can only contain a password. Another one is "username with password" that can contain both a username and a password. I am not aware of a type of credential that holds host.

Comment: @MaratC I would prefer the one with username and secrect key.

Comment: Why don't you create one then?

Comment: @MaratC I may repeat this procedure several times to create different ssh-logins. I am wondering whether this can be done by script.